# no mouse at /dev/input/mouse0 after upgrade to Debian Buster

Tags: linux, mouse, raspberry-pi, input-device, debian-buster

After upgrading my headless Raspberry Pi 2B to Raspbian/Debian Buster (and reboots), the USB mouse stopped writing to /dev/input/mouse0; the follwoing command remains silent when I move the mouse or click a mouse button:

```
sudo cat /dev/input/mouse0
```

1) The mouse (hardware) works, tested on another RPi (Raspbian/Debian Stretch).

2) The kernel detects when I unplug and re-plug the mouse:

```
[64593.590044] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 6
[75909.126278] usb 1-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[75909.261147] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1a, idProduct=0000, bcdDevice= 1.10
[75909.261165] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[75909.261173] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Mouse
[75909.267788] input: USB Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:1B1A:0000.0002/input/input1
[75909.268567] hid-generic 0003:1B1A:0000.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [USB Mouse] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input0
```

3) /dev/input/mouse0 disappears when I unplug the mouse and reappears after re-plug:

```
$ ls -lA /dev/input
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      80 Jan 26 11:59 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      80 Jan 26 11:59 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 64 Jan 26 11:59 event0
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 63 Jan 25 14:54 mice
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 32 Jan 26 11:59 mouse0
```

What else should I try to get the mouse back to work? Thanks for hints, where I should look.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**: the mouse was grabbed by another process.

How I got there: I installed evtest (`sudo apt install evtest`), then run `evtest` that told me why the events are not available to it. evtest also told me that `sudo fuser -v /dev/input/event0` will show which process has grabbed the mouse. In my case it is Kodi; the update to Buster installed a new version with apparently different behaviour. After `sudo systemctl stop kodi`, I can again read from /dev/input/mouse0.